# Making Trace Colors Consistency Across Figures/Graphs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Let's say I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash


df_a = pd.DataFrame({"time":pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-nov-2021","2-nov-2021", freq="S")).sample(30),
             "bacteria_count":np.random.randint(0,500, 30), "bacteria_type":np.random.choice(list("AB"),30)})

df_a["epoch_time_ms"] = df_a["time"].astype(int) / 1000
df_a = df_a.sort_values("time")
fig_a = px.line(df_a, x="time", y="bacteria_count", line_shape="hv", markers=True, color='bacteria_type')
fig_a.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig_a.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')


df_b = pd.DataFrame({"time":pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-nov-2021","2-nov-2021", freq="S")).sample(30),
             "bacteria_count":np.random.randint(0,500, 30), "bacteria_type":np.random.choice(list("BC"),30)})
df_b["epoch_time_ms"] = df_b["time"].astype(int) / 1000
df_b = df_b.sort_values("time")
fig_b = px.line(df_b, x="epoch_time_ms", y="bacteria_count", line_shape="hv", markers=True, color='bacteria_type')
fig_b.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig_b.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')


app = dash.Dash(__name__)  # call flask server
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
                          html.Div([
                              html.Div([
                                  html.H1(children='G_A'),
                                  dcc.Graph(id='fig_a-graph', figure=fig_a)
                              ], className='six columns'),
                              html.Div([
                                  html.H1(children='G_B'),
                                  dcc.Graph(id='fig_b-graph', figure=fig_b)
                              ], className='six columns')
                          ])])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8086)
```

I want to achieve:

1. Traces in both figures/graphs are consistent and unique such that the color for trace 'B' in both figures is the same and the color for trace 'A' won't be used as the color for trace 'C' (nor 'B').
2. Sometimes, I have like 20 traces in each graphs, it would be great if plotly can select more distinctive colors for all traces as sometimes, it is hard to tell which one is which when the colors of multiple trades are different but very similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach is to concatenate your data and use facets.  Therefore legend is shared and consistent.  The *trick* I've used here is create an additional column on concatenation that can be used as `facet_row`

```
px.line(
    pd.concat([df_a.assign(df="a"), df_b.assign(df="b")]),
    x="epoch_time_ms",
    y="bacteria_count",
    facet_row="df",
    line_shape="hv",
    markers=True,
    color="bacteria_type",
).update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None).update_layout(
    hovermode="x unified"
)
```

[image]

#### approach 2

- define your own color map `cmap` in this example
- ensure that you look across all *bacteria types* and use and approach to assigning a color within **dict** comprehension

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash


df_a = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-nov-2021", "2-nov-2021", freq="S")).sample(
            30
        ),
        "bacteria_count": np.random.randint(0, 500, 30),
        "bacteria_type": np.random.choice(list("AB"), 30),
    }
)

df_a["epoch_time_ms"] = df_a["time"].astype(int) / 1000
df_a = df_a.sort_values("time")
df_b = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-nov-2021", "2-nov-2021", freq="S")).sample(
            30
        ),
        "bacteria_count": np.random.randint(0, 500, 30),
        "bacteria_type": np.random.choice(list("BC"), 30),
    }
)
df_b["epoch_time_ms"] = df_b["time"].astype(int) / 1000
df_b = df_b.sort_values("time")

# use whatever approach you want to assign a color to a bacteria type
# key loop through all bacteria types
cmap = {
    bt: px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[i % len(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)]
    for i, bt in enumerate(pd.concat([df_a, df_b])["bacteria_type"].unique())
}

fig_a = px.line(
    df_a,
    x="time",
    y="bacteria_count",
    line_shape="hv",
    markers=True,
    color="bacteria_type",
    color_discrete_map=cmap,
)
fig_a.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig_a.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")


fig_b = px.line(
    df_b,
    x="epoch_time_ms",
    y="bacteria_count",
    line_shape="hv",
    markers=True,
    color="bacteria_type",
    color_discrete_map=cmap,
)
fig_b.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig_b.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

# app = dash.Dash(__name__)  # call flask server
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H1(children="G_A"),
                        dcc.Graph(id="fig_a-graph", figure=fig_a),
                    ],
                    className="six columns",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H1(children="G_B"),
                        dcc.Graph(id="fig_b-graph", figure=fig_b),
                    ],
                    className="six columns",
                ),
            ]
        )
    ]
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run_server(debug=True, port=8086)
    # app.run_server(debug=True, port=8086)
    app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Both approaches have their good use cases.  I wonder whether there is a way to make the colors in the map more distinctive visually (my question #2) dynamically?  I just tried your approach #1 with 9 lines.  Some still have pretty close colors.

Comment: you can use a different discrete sequence https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express    On building the colors yourself, you can also define your own static list that you source from somewhere else.  IMHO plotly has done quite a lot on color design, and being red/green color blind not something I can really do

Comment: Ah, I know the issue -- `len(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)` is only 10...so when I have 11 lines, certainly there is a duplicate....my eyes are still okay :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think what you need is this: https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/

Scroll down (or search) for "color_discrete_map"

Essentially, you can create a dict specifying "Trace A" should use color 1, "Trace B" should use color 2, etc

Then specify in all the relevant figures/graphs to use the same dict as color_discrete_map